# Python - Can't find module after successfully installing

Tags: python-3.x

I installed pyHook
In my .py file I go to import:

"import pyHook"

I get an error that says module not found.

I found the module inside of site-packages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't access Python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834387/cant-access-python-modules)

Comment: You'll have to provide more details. What OS? How did you install pyHook? Are you using a virtual env? What Python version? Are you using multiple versions of Python? Where exactly did you find the module (path to site-packages)? etc..